# Solve the surd equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$ \sqrt{14+ 8\sqrt{3}} = 2\sqrt{2} + b$$

Find b without using factoring

b=sqrt{6}

Comment: OP, please confirm that this is your original equation.

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Other than saying that $b=\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}-2\sqrt{2}$ is a perfectly correct answer, I will tell you that

$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{a-c}{2}}
$$
where $c^2=a^2-b$.

Comment: Should the last equation be $c^2=a^2-b$?

Comment: I didn't understang guys

Comment: You can write $\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}$ as $\sqrt{14+\sqrt{64\cdot 3}}$. Then use the formula I wrote, with $a=14$ and $b=64\cdot 3$.

Comment: @sofr1na  Alternatively, you can set $\sqrt{14 + 8\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, square both sides to obtain $14 + 8\sqrt{3} = a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}$ (with $a$ and $b$ being rational numbers), then solve the system of equations $a + b = 14$ and $2\sqrt{ab} = 8\sqrt{3}$.  bartgol is providing you with a general formula for simplifying the expression $\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}}$.

Comment: but notice that the true answer is b=sqrt6 those solution which you suggested don't give me that answer

Comment: Are you sure? I get $\sqrt{6}$ with the formula I gave you...

Comment: @bartgol, is there any other way of proving than squaring the expression:$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}$?

Comment: In order to prove the nested radicals formula I mentioned in the answer, I think squaring is the only way I know. It's also the most natural way.